# Stargazer isn't performing summary statistics on ALL of my columns

Tags: r, stargazer

These are my column names:

`colnames(QTrain70)`

``` [1] "Depth"``"Garage_Spa"``"Total_Liva"``"NEAR_DIST.Vac" ```
``` [5]"NEAR_DIST.ComCor"``"NEAR_DIST.LIViol"``"NEAR_DIST.Retail"``"NEAR_DIST.SeptST" ```

`[9] "NEAR_DIST.TrafDat"` ``` "NEAR_DIST.HwyEx"``"Sale_Pri_1"``"Tax_Build"``
[13] "Tax_Land" ```

However my stargazer code : 
`stargazer(QTrain70, type="text", title = "Summary Statistics")`

Only returns summary statistics for 5 of the 13 columns.

Specifically these 5:

`Garage_Spa 170,227    0.308       0.613      0       72

Total_Liva 170,227  1,308.933    733.466     0     29,524

Sale_Pri_1 169,295 126,100.400 229,805.900 1,001 30,000,000
Tax_Build  170,227 98,574.050  97,399.690    0   2,310,000 
Tax_Land   170,227 31,967.470  45,871.640    0   5,088,300`

I want it to output statistics for all of the columns. Why would it not go through all the columns?

Comment: Check data types with `str(QTrain70)`, are the missing ones factors or non-numeric?

Comment: @Parfait the missing ones are factors and the ones showing up are `int`. How do I transform them?

Comment: `as.integer(as.character(QTrain70$colname))`

Comment: @Parfait  all that does is cause R to print out all of the observations in the column and then stop and print ` [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 160227 entries ]` After checking if the character has changed to `is.integer(QTrain70$NEAR_DIST.Retail)` for example it reports `False`

Comment: You have to assign it (thought that goes without saying): `QTrain70$colname <- as.integer(as.character(QTrain70$colname))`

Comment: @Parfait Strangely enough after these have been transformed into integers they still don't show up in the core plot output.

Comment: Your original question concerns `stargazer()`. Do all 13 summary statistics output after integer conversion? I am not seeing a plot line. Do only the original 5 show up in this plot? Or none? Be sure assignment is run prior to these methods.

Comment: @Parfait you're right. The plot line is simply `corrplot (QTrain70, method = "number")` these same variables are the showing perfect correlation with themselves but not with other variables in the list. Any thoughts?

Comment: *Same*, *other*...please be specific. The original 5? The other 8 out of 13 converted too integer? What are the types of first 5? Possibly they have decimal precision as `numeric` type vs `integer` type.

Comment: @Parfait, the 8 out of the 13 converted to integer are each respectively showing correlation with themselves. Any variable starting with `NEAR` shows correlation with other variables also starting with `NEAR` but not with the remainder of variables. The remaining 5 show correlation amongst themselves as well.